# c# reference to non-static class members in a class nested struct

Tags: c#, class, struct, nested

I got a `struct S` as nested declaration in a `class C`, where I'd like to refere to members of `C` in the constructor of `S`:

```
public class C {
    private int class_state = 0;
    
    private struct S {
        public int struct_state;
        
        public S () {
            struct_state = class_state;
        }
    }

    public void foo (int state) {
        class_state = state;
    }
    
    public void bar () {
        S s = new S();
    }
}
```

Yielding an error, that `class_state` is non-static and therefore needs an reference to an instance of `C`.

Is there an *implicit* way to tell `struct S` to reference the instance it is instanciated in?

Comment: No, The struct has no idea which instace of the enclosing class is constructing it.

Comment: What is the problem with just passing in `this` to the constructor of `S`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Unlike in Java, C# [Nested Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) don't have an "imilicit" or "automatic" reference to the instance of the enclosing type.

"A nested type has access to all of the members that are accessible to its containing type. It can access private and protected members of the containing type, including any inherited protected members."

but:

"To access the containing type, **pass it as an argument to the constructor of the nested type**. "